# Changing variable value in base html template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I need to change value of variable `login_status` in base html template, which is used for every html page in 
web application.

Tech: jinja2, python.

If login into personal account is successful, then `login_status` got string value 'logout',
if not - 'login'. But correct change happens only in one page of personal account, when I jump
to another pages this variable does not change and  has default value.

Please help me to handle this, show the way to change this variable on every html page.

Thank you!

base.html

```
<li class="in">{{login_status | default('login')}}</li>
 <form name="form_in" method = 'post' action = '/personal_account'>
       <input type="text"  placeholder="Login" id="log" name="login"/>
       <input type="password"  placeholder="Password" id="pass" name="password"/>
       <input type="submit"/>
 </form>
```

python function

```
@app.route('/personal_account', methods=['POST'])
    def welcome():
        login = request.form['login']
        password = request.form['password']
        login_status = u'logout'
        if not validate_user(login, password):
            login_status = u'login'
            return u'Incorrect login!', login_status
        data = get_user_data(login)
        return render_template('private.html',
                               data=data,
                               login_status=login_status)
```

**EDIT ONE**

I would like to check the user's status just once, then save it and walk through pages of my application without sending check request to server each time I change html-page. The click event on the button "exit" causes changing user's status. Is it possible to do that? And if so then how?

Comment: I assume that you're also using Flask?

Comment: Yes. I am using Flask

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to actually accomplish that, and one of the simplest ways would be attaching a currently logged in user object to global application context:

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.user = None
    # Now this is your application specific code:
    if 'user_id' in session:
        g.user = load_user_info(user_id)
```

And now you can use this object in template:

```
 {% if g.user %}
 User is logged in
 {% else %}
 User not logged in
 {% endif %}
```

[Edit]: Another option would be to rely on Flask's session which defaults to client-side cookies by default. Just go through the [Sessions quickstart in docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#sessions).

Comment: As far as I understand you offer to send a request to the server every time user goes to any html page. Is there a better alternative if I am not keen to check user status every time when he goes to any page on my web app. Is there a better option not using a global flag?

Comment: How else would you check whether user is actually logged in?

Comment: @John well, I did not really know whether the question was actually about Flask ;)

Comment: Honestly, I don't think that this question is related to Flask, it is more about general aspect of interaction including html-flask-jinja2

Comment: And I do not think that your question is really helpfull according to Edit One...